# WPF Bind to a Collection of objects, sorted by IDs stored in order in another Collection in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, sorting, collections

For those of you that like puzzles: I had this problem recently and am sure there must be a nicer solution.

Consider :

- an ObservableCollection of **Foo** objects called *foos*.
- **Foo** contains a string ID field
- I have no control over *foos*
- *foos* will be changing

Then:

- I have another collection called *sortLikeThis*
- *sortListThis* contains strings
- The strings are the IDs in the order in which the *foos* are to be shown

Plus:

- There may be objects in *foos* with an ID that is not in *sortLikeThis*. These need to go at the end.
- Likewise, there may be strings in *sortLikeThis* that do not appear in *foos*.

Is there a nice way to bind to and show in wpf the **Foo** objects in *foos* in the order defined by IDs in *sortLikeThis* ?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for a custom observable collection that implements IEnumerable and has a pretty little enumerator (aaah, yield) that handles the logic of the custom sort.

```
public class SortFoosLolThx : ObservableCollection<Foo> {
public IList<string> SortList {/*...*/}
/*...*/
public override IEnumerator<Foo> GetEnumerator() { /*...*/ yield foo; /*...*/}
}
```

Comment: Hi Will,

I'm not sure this solution works:

1. I have no control over the ObservableCollection<Foo> **foos** - so in particular, can not turn it into a sortable one.

2. What would trigger a call to SortList if the collection was modified?

Lee

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Bindable LINQ](http://www.paulstovell.com/blog/category/bindablelinq)? It allows you to define LINQ queries on top of an observable collection, and makes sure that the LINQ query is performed each time the underlying collection is changed. In your case, you could add an Orderby query on top of the collection.

You can pass the Orderby method a delegate to do the comparison. To set this up you would

1. Prepare by creating a Dictionary mapping each id in sortLikeThis to an ascending int
2. Within the comparison delegate, lookup in the dictionary the ids of the two foos that are passed for comparison. Do the appropriate thing if an item cannot be found.